# Threshold ramps

Tags: tools

It being springtime I am topping up my raised beds with compost. Instead of getting individual 50 litre bags I'd like to get a larger delivery.

The trouble is I'm in a mid-terrace, so access to the garden is through the house. Do I need a special threshold ramp to be able to take a wheelbarrow full of compost through the front and rear doors without damage, or is a simple plank arrangement OK?

Comment: I can't help but think that by the time you lay down a tarp, don't fill the wheelbarrow too full, don't ding the walls with the wheel barrow you could have moved the same amount of bags...

Comment: @kevinsky given the need to ramp over the front door, the back door, the odd down up "moat" before the patio and then the steps up to the garden I'm not sure you're wrong. But it's too late to think things through now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find a plank just fine. If convenient lay scrap carpet ( or canvas, old blankets etc) through the house - dirt will get tracked in.

Comment: Turns out it was just fine. Thanks for the reassuring answer.